# Doubly circular linked list strange behaviour

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I use the following code snippet to add an element to the back of my doubly circular linked list.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int nb;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
} st_node;

void add_back(st_node *origin, st_node *node)
{
    st_node *tmp;

    if (!origin || !node)
        exit(1);
    tmp = origin;
    while (tmp->next != origin)
        tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp->next = node;
    node->prev = tmp;
    node->next = origin;
    origin->prev = node;
}
```

Then I print my list with the folling function :

```
void    printer(st_node *origin)
{
    st_node *node;

    node = origin;
    while (node->next != origin)
    {
        printf("%d\n", node->nb);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("%d\n", node->nb);
}
```

I got the origin value with printf and then random values in a loop. I don't know what to do and I realized `origin->prev = node;` was causing the problem inside the `add_back` function but I don't know why.

Here's the main:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    st_node     *stack;
    int         i;

    if (ac <= 2)
        return (1);
    stack = create_element(atoi(av[1]));
    i = 2;
    while (i < ac)
        add_back(stack, create_element(atoi(av[i++])));
    printf("Stack:\n");
    printer(stack);
}
```

```
st_node *create_element(int nb)
{
    st_node *element;
    element = malloc(sizeof(st_node *));
    element->nb = nb;
    element->next = element;
    element->prev = element;
    return (element);
}
```

Comment: If your list is doubly-linked and circular, then why iterate all the way through to find the last node?  Shouldn't it simply be `origin->prev`?

Comment: Of course, assuming and enforcing that `origin` is not null is only sensible if the list has a dummy node to serve as origin. But that's certainly the way I would and do write such lists.  It makes most of the internals simpler.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. That is, please provide the `main` and any other minimal code needed such that anyone can take the code exactly as shown and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I used to have a function inside the loop to check if the number we're going to add was not already added before. I do this to check and avoid duplicated numbers

Comment: @kaylum I updated the thread

Comment: Note that if you indeed do have a dummy node to serve as origin, then your `printer()` function should skip that node instead of printing its value.  And whether you have a dummy origin node or not, you must *not* skip printing the node immediately preceding it (unless that node is the origin itself).

Comment: How add_back is being called in your code?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(st_node *));` needs to be `malloc(sizeof(st_node));` or `malloc(sizeof(*element));`

Comment: I updated. Everything is provided now.

Comment: It's technically still not complete. Missing includes and I doubt that's the exact order of the function definitions in your real file. It's ok cause it's mostly there. But for future posts please provide the full and exact code as well as place it in a single block. Makes it easier for others to just copy the full block and run it.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, it helps to get real numbers. Now, I have my numbers but they are printed in an infinite loop

Comment: In `create_element`, `element = malloc(sizeof(st_node *));` --> `element = malloc(sizeof(st_node));` Better yet is `element = malloc(sizeof(*element));`

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it to trace it as it runs to find out why it is in an infinete loop. More debugging tips here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Yes thanks @CraigEstey I edited and it solved my problem of wrong values but I still don't know why I have an infite loop.

Comment: What infinite loop, @zelph14?  You didn't mention that before, and the code you presented (as corrected) does not exhibit infinite looping for me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I wrote 'random values in a loop' but this loop is infinite. The integers are printer in the correct order but in an infinite loop.

Comment: Well, we can't guess what may be wrong with code that you have not presented.  We asked for a [mre], and you claimed to have provided one.  That MRE does not reproduce infinite looping.

Comment: In `add_back`, `tmp = origin->prev;` and remove the `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

Your `create_element()` function is wrong.  It does not allocate enough memory for each node.  This ...

> ```
>     st_node *element;
>     element = malloc(sizeof(st_node *));
> ```

... should be ...

```
    st_node *element;
    element = malloc(sizeof(st_node));
```

... or, better ...

```
    st_node *element;
    element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
```

With that correction, and adding a closing brace to `main()`, your program works for me.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me to avoid wrong values but I still get an infinite loop.

Comment: @zelph14, As I already wrote in this answer, with the correction I describe, your program works for me.  By which I mean that when run with at least two integers as command-line arguments, it prints them, in order, then terminates.  I see no infinite looping, nor any reason in the code to expect it.

Comment: Problem solved, I just forgot to edit my code. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Several bugs:

1. `malloc` in `create_element` is wrong
2. In `add_back`, the order of the link setting is wrong
3. In `add_back`, no need to loop to find the tail node. It is `origin->prev`
4. The `printer` function will segfault on an *empty* list because it is dereferencing `node` before checking whether it is non-null
5. The first `if` in `main` is too strict: It does *not* allow: `./myprogram 1` (i.e. a list with one element)

---

Here is the refactored/working code. It is annotated with the bugs/fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int nb;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
} st_node;

st_node *
create_element(int nb)
{
    st_node *element;

// NOTE/BUG: does _not_ allocate enough space (causing UB/undefined behavior)
#if 0
    element = malloc(sizeof(st_node *));
#else
    element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
#endif
    element->nb = nb;
    element->next = element;
    element->prev = element;
    return (element);
}

void
add_back(st_node *origin, st_node *node)
{
    st_node *tmp;

    if (!origin || !node)
        exit(1);

// NOTE/BUG: no need to traverse -- origin->prev is the back
#if 0
    tmp = origin;
    while (tmp->next != origin)
        tmp = tmp->next;
#else
    tmp = origin->prev;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: order and set is incorrect -- causes self loop
#if 0
    tmp->next = node;
    node->prev = tmp;
    node->next = origin;
#else
    node->prev = tmp;
    node->next = tmp->next;
    tmp->next = node;
#endif
    origin->prev = node;
}

void
printer(st_node *origin)
{
    st_node *node;

// NOTE/BUG: this will segfault on an empty list
#if 1
    node = origin;
    while (node->next != origin) {
        printf("%d\n", node->nb);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("%d\n", node->nb);
#else
    node = origin;
    if (node != NULL) {
        while (1) {
            printf("%d\n", node->nb);
            node = node->next;
            if (node == origin)
                break;
        }
    }
#endif
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    st_node *stack;
    int i;

// NOTE/BUG: does _not_ allow for list of only one element
#if 0
    if (ac <= 2) {
#else
    if (ac < 2) {
#endif
        printf("main: too short\n");
        return (1);
    }
    stack = create_element(atoi(av[1]));

// NOTE/BUG: for loop is cleaner
#if 0
    i = 2;
    while (i < ac)
        add_back(stack, create_element(atoi(av[i++])));
#else
    for (i = 2;  i < ac;  ++i)
        add_back(stack, create_element(atoi(av[i])));
#endif

    printf("Stack:\n");
    printer(stack);
}
```

In the above, I used `cpp` conditionals to denote old/broken vs. new/fixed code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

---

The above code fixed most of the bugs, but the program could not create an empty list.

Here's some more cleanup/refactoring to make the program more general. In particular, I generalized `add_back` to allow adding a node to an *empty* list. In the original code, it treated this as a fatal exit condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int nb;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
} st_node;

st_node *
create_element(int nb)
{
    st_node *element;

    element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
    element->nb = nb;
    element->next = element;
    element->prev = element;
    return (element);
}

st_node *
add_back(st_node *origin, st_node *node)
{
    st_node *tmp;

    if (node == NULL)
        exit(1);

    do {
        // add to empty list
        if (origin == NULL) {
            origin = node;
            break;
        }

        tmp = origin->prev;

        node->prev = tmp;
        node->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = node;
        origin->prev = node;
    } while (0);

    return origin;
}

void
printer(st_node *origin)
{
    st_node *node;

    node = origin;
    if (node != NULL) {
        while (1) {
            printf("%d\n", node->nb);
            node = node->next;
            if (node == origin)
                break;
        }
    }
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    st_node *stack = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i = 1;  i < ac;  ++i)
        stack = add_back(stack, create_element(atoi(av[i])));

    printf("Stack:\n");
    printer(stack);
}
```